# Laravel 5 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Category' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

guys following the tuts tutorial for laravel , Since I have installed Laravel 5 couple of errors are throwing .

**Code**

```
public function getIndex() {
        return View::make('categories.index')
            ->with('categories', Category::all());
    }
```

This function is throwing two errors

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Category' not found
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\views' not found
```

Well I know this is because of the different name spacing in Laravel 5 . for the 2nd error I tried to add

`use view` at the begining of the file but it is not finding the view . Can any one let me know what directory these files resides

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those are not in your Controllers. The View class is apart of Illuminate and the other one is most likely a class Model you created.

When you use a new class in a php file you must include it or `use` it.

The way you would most likely do this for your Category class is"

`use App\Category` that should solve that one.

Your view one is only slightly more difficult. If you use an IDE where you can import classes that is much easier to do so you don't have to remember the namespace / class name. However, if you don't you need to know which one to use and when to use it. In this case you will need to do:

`use View` this should solve this.

So in your controller above the declaration and below your namespace you must put the use calls

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers

// I'm removing this because there is a way not to even have to use this...
// use View;
use App\Category;

class YourController extends Controller {
    ...
}
```

Like I mentioned in my comment there is a better way. You could just use the helper function `view()` to return the view just the same without doing the view the way you are doing it.

All you have to change is:

```
return View::make('categories.index')->with('categories', Category::all());
```

to

```
return view('categories.index', ['categories' => Category::all()]);
    or
return view('categories.index')->with('categories',Category::all())
```

Removes the confusion of messing up the classes.

Comment: after applying your method `Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\View::make()`

Comment: Follow the rest of the instructions. Like I said there were some question on that. So it means that the Facade is the right one, but that is not the best way to do this. I'll also edit my answer to remove the other one to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just `use View` will suffice if you're using the Facade.

Comment: Thank you Ben you're right.. I forgot that was an option.

Comment: @Vikram I still stand by don't use it any way. Use the helper function and don't even worry about the include class.

Comment: @CayceK whilst using `view()` helpers would work, it doesn't help the OP work out why the current solution isn't working and thus doesn't help OP understand how to use other classes moving forward, one without a helper function perhaps.

Comment: @BenSwinburne agreed in the overall, but if I can both teach why they failed with the top part of the answer and include a better solution with the second half I believe that is a better teaching route as using Laravel to its fullest is a better decision than to use the classes that they don't need to use.

Comment: @CayceK this worked , `use App\categories_table;
use Illuminate\View\View;`

Comment: I mean the category class was called categories_table and for view I added the above code . Please update your answer .

Comment: @Vikram Since you made that comment I won't. that is more direct to your setup. Laravel follows a fairly common naming structure. I think it would be best to leave it as is as you *technically* should name your category the same in most cases, but obviously that isn't always the case. I'm glad this helped you though!

Answer (score 2):

add following at top of file just below `namespace` declaration,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Category;
```

Comment: where is your `Category`  class defined. I presumed it is defined in `app` directory with `namespace App;`